# How do I quickly move the cursor to the end in bash in vi mode?

Tags: bash, vi

When I'm in insert mode and I move left from the last cursor position (the empty spot to the right of the last character), then I can't go back to that position anymore. I have to type <kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>$</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> (or replace <kbd>$</kbd> with <kbd>→</kbd> a bunch of times) to get there. It seems like a lot of extra keystrokes just to, say, go delete the last character (and still be in insert mode).

Is there a better way or should I just use the default emacs mode (even though I don't know a single emacs command)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In normal mode you start edit at end of line with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

In insert mode you should be able to move to EOL.

In manual:

```
man readline
/VI Mode bindings<Enter>
```

---

As to *real/other* question, I have to fill in a bit:

```
$ le eds de x
      ^     ^^
      |     ||
      A     BC
```

In insert mode do you mean you are not able to move to `C`, only `B` from `A`?

Even with <kbd>→</kbd>, or <kbd>End</kbd>?

So that if you start typing  the letters will enter before `x`?

Comment: I can't go back to `C` once I leave that position in insert mode. So if I move all the way to the left and start typing, the `x` character will always be the last character. Also I don't have a `End` key (MacBook Pro).

Comment: @hobbes3: Also, do you have an `.inputrc` file?

Comment: No, I don't. Is there anything else I should test for? I have noticed that I can get to `C` on CentOS with `set -o vi` in my `.bashrc`. I think this problem is specific to Mac OS X's Terminal.

Comment: @hobbes3: Could you try `bash --norc --noprofile` followed by `set -o vi` – to see if it is some configuration file creating the issue.

Comment: I did that and it's doing the same thing (can't get to `C`). So weird. It must be a Mac Terminal limitation...

Comment: @hobbes3: Sounds like a bug then. (Hard to argue for it as a *feature*.) I posted a ping/question with link here on chat @ http://apple.stackexchange.com

Comment: I have the same bug on a 2013 macbook air running OSX 10.9.2.  I'm also using iTerm instead of the built-in graphical terminal, but I get the same behaviour in the built-in version.

Answer (score 4):

You can just press the `End` key to get there.

Also, you can use `Shift + A` (capital A - for *append*) to put you into Insert Mode at the end of a line.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old question, but I've been beating my head over this for a few days now and I've finally got it. It turns out the solution is simple: **update bash to 4.3**. The default bash on Macs (even Yosemite) is 3.2.

Install Homebrew with

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

then do

```
brew install bash
```

then change your default shell path (in Terminal Preferences) to

```
/usr/local/bin/bash
```

and that's it. Check your bash version with

```
bash --version
```

and as an added bonus, you can get mode indicators!

```
bind 'set show-mode-in-prompt on'
```

and it will show a `+` for Insert mode and `:` for Command mode.

Comment: This had been bugging me for so long - thank you! : ) btw I upgraded with macports - `sudo port install bash` then set Command in terminal preferences to `/opt/local/bin/bash`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:10000` or more to get to the last line

Comment: `:x` move to a given line, not within the line.